# Java - Which Layout Manager should I use for my program?

Tags: java, swing, layout, applet

[image: Program]

Originally I wanted to use Border Layout but you can only use up to 9 boxes from my understanding. Is this true or not?

Also is there something more easier than GridBagLayout yet more flexible than Grid Layout?

Comment: I think you should use a vertical box layout and use a horizontal box layout for your rows like box7-9.

Comment: Use [`TableLayout`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/tablelayout-141489.html) manager as an alternative to `GridBagLayout`

Comment: I don't know if you have checked this page yet, but it's very useful information on using layour managers. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: You can use multiple layout managers to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine 2 border and 1 grid layout.

The outer border layout will contain titlle on north, and other panel with border layout in the center.

The second panel will contain subtitle at north and grid layout with 2 lines only in the center.

The grid layout can contain other grid layout 3*3 for buttons on the upper line and border layout with with large box at the center.

Alternative solution is using `GridBagLayout`. However you should do some exercises with it to get it working.

Other solution is using `MigLayout` - the third party open source solution that allows creating any view very simply.